# why does useFonts hook worked on Android but not on iOS using React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use a custom Font on React Native using useFonts hook. This component works perfectly on Android but doesn't render anything on iOS. I've also tried `Font.loadAsync` but that too didn't render anything. Thoughts? (edit: iOS is on version 15.2)

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

export default function AppText({ children, size, color, fontFamily }) {

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Montserrat-Regular': require('../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
    'Montserrat-Medium': require('../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
    'Montserrat-SemiBold': require('../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'Montserrat-Bold': require('../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'),
    'Montserrat-Black': require('../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Black.ttf'),
    'Montserrat-Light': require('../../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Text 
      style={{
        fontFamily: fontFamily || 'Montserrat-Regular',
        fontSize: size || 16,
        color: color || 'black',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but apparently a simple device restart (the computer, not the iPhone emulator) did the trick for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).